# Delete seriescollection datalabels

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remove `Data Labels` from my `SeriesCollection` if it is `True`. However, I am facing the error below:

`Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Delete' of object 'DataLabels' failed`

The below code works when sheet is unprotected. When I protect the sheet and select the below then the error occurs. Chart is left unlocked.

1. Select locked cells
2. Select unlocked cells
3. Use PivotTable & PivotChart
4. Edit Objects

Code as below:

```
Sub RemoveDataLabels()
    Dim BackgroundData As Series
    Set BackgroundData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart.SeriesCollection("Series1")
        
    With BackgroundData
        If .HasDataLabels = True Then
            .DataLabels.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Edit:
The code is now working with this addition, thanks @SiddharthRout

```
Sub RemoveDataLabels()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    ' Protect the sheet
    ws.Protect Contents:=False
    
    Dim BackgroundData As Series
    Set BackgroundData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart.SeriesCollection("Series1")
    
    With BackgroundData
    
        If .HasDataLabels = True Then
        .DataLabels.Delete
        End If
        
    End With
    
    ' Reprotect the sheet
    ws.Protect Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, DrawingObjects:=True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This should work. Possible to see your excel file? If yes then remove any confidential data and share it on a site like wikisend.com and share the link here. Alternatively you can use dropbox, onedrive etc...

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for looking at this. I have edited my question to be more precise about it (sorry for leaving it out earlier). It only fails and shows error message when I protect my sheet. The chart is left unlocked.

Comment: If I am not wrong then this is a very old bug.. discovered way back in 2010 or 2012 (my memory is faliling me). You will have to unprotect the sheet at the begining of the code and reprotect it in the end.